# How to mock a Python system attribute like os.pathsep?

Tags: python, mocking, python-mock

I am trying to modify a test to handle both Linux and Windows. The code being tested uses `os.pathsep`. Example:

```py
def path_split(pth):
    if os.pathsep in pth:
        return pth.split(os.pathsep)
    else:
        return [pth]
```

If I run the following test on Linux using a colon, it works:

```py
class PathsepTest(TestCase):

    def test_path_split(self):
        result = path_split("foo:bar")
        assert result == ["foo", "bar"]
```

However, if I try to mock `os.pathsep` to return the Windows path separator (`;`)

```py
class PathsepTest(TestCase):

    def test_path_split(self):
        windows_pathsep = ";"
        with patch.object(os, "pathsep", return_value=windows_pathsep):
            result = path_split("foo;bar")
            assert result == ["foo", "bar"]
```

it fails with

```
    def path_split(pth):
>       if os.pathsep in pth:
E       TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not MagicMock
```

For a simpler function

```py
def get_pathsep():
    return os.pathsep
```

the corresponding test fails if I do

```py
    def test_get_pathsep(self):
        windows_pathsep = ";"
        with patch.object(os, "pathsep", return_value=windows_pathsep):
            result = get_pathsep()
            assert result == windows_pathsep
```

but passes if I do

```py
            assert result.return_value == windows_pathsep
```

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mock.patch` replace an object by another, default is to replace with a [`MagicMock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.MagicMock).

So `patch.object(os, "pathsep", return_value=":")`, replace `os.pathsep` by a `MagicMock`. Then `return_value` specify the behavior when you call the mock object (ie. `os.pathsep.__call__`)

```py
>>> with mock.patch("os.pathsep", return_value=";"):
...     print(os.pathsep())   # os.pathsep has been replaced by a callable
... 
;
```

But `os.pathsep` isn't a callable object, it is `str`. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch), you can simply replace the orginal object by another with the `new` argument:

```py
>>> with mock.patch("os.pathsep", new=";"):
...     print(os.pathsep)
... 
;
```